# Frobenius norm derivative for a quadratic form

Tags: matrices, derivatives, normed-spaces, matrix-calculus

I have the following loss function:

$\vert\vert Y - XBX^{\top} \vert\vert_F^2$

where $Y, X$ and $B$ are square and symmetric matrices and $\vert \vert \cdot \vert \vert$ denotes the Frobenius norm. Which is the derivative of the loss function with respect to $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned}
&\frac{ ‖ Y - XBX^⊤ ‖_F^2}{ X}
\\ &=\frac{ ‖ Y - XBX^⊤ ‖_F^2}{(Y - XBX^⊤)} ∘ \frac{ (Y - XBX^⊤)}{ X}
\\ &= [{∆Z}↦2⟨Y - XBX^⊤∣{∆Z}⟩_F] ∘ [{∆X} ↦ XB{∆X}^⊤ + {∆X}BX^⊤]
\\ &= [{∆X} ⟼  2⟨Y - XBX^⊤∣XB{∆X}^⊤ + {∆X}BX^⊤⟩_F]
\\ &\text{To get the derivative in tensorial form, we need to move everything except ${∆X}$ to the left.}
\\ &= [{∆X} ⟼  2⟨Y - XBX^⊤∣XB{∆X}^⊤⟩_F + 2⟨Y - XBX^⊤∣{∆X}BX^⊤⟩_F]
\\ &= [{∆X} ⟼  ⟨2B^⊤X^⊤(Y - XBX^⊤)∣{∆X}^⊤⟩_F + ⟨2(Y - XBX^⊤)XB^⊤∣{∆X}⟩_F]
\\ &= [{∆X} ⟼  ⟨2(Y - XBX^⊤)^⊤XB∣{∆X}⟩_F + ⟨2(Y - XBX^⊤)XB^⊤∣{∆X}⟩_F]
\\ &= [{∆X} ⟼  ⟨4(Y - XBX^⊤)XB∣{∆X}⟩_F]
\end{aligned}$$